# Proof of factor by induction

Tags: induction

> Prove by mathematical induction that $4$ is a factor of $9^n - 5^n\,\forall n\geq1$.

Please have a look at my attempt if it is correct or not.
[image]

Comment: yup looks good..

Comment: do I need to add more steps?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok, except the last line where you used $ 4(9k+5^n) = 4n.$

As you notice, n is used to mean two different things.

Change the last $4n$ to $4m$ and you have a good proof.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.